# why I am getting the .BIN format of the image formed from the bitmap when sharing it over different apps

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting the .bin format of the image, which i am trying to share it over different apps. I had generated this image from the bitmap, which in turn is formed from the scrollView with the help of the canvas drawing.

```
private fun takeScreenshotAndShare(scrollView: ScrollView) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // Taking screenshot of the ScrollView
            val screenshotBitmap = takeScrollViewScreenshot(scrollView)

            // Compressing the bitmap on a background thread
            val compressedImageFile = compressBitmapAsync(screenshotBitmap)

            // Sharing the compressed image file
            
            shareImage(compressedImageFile)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun takeScrollViewScreenshot(scrollView: ScrollView): Bitmap {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                scrollView.getChildAt(0).measuredWidth,
                scrollView.getChildAt(0).measuredHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            scrollView.draw(canvas)
            bitmap
        }
    }

private suspend fun compressBitmapAsync(bitmap: Bitmap): File {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val imagesFolder = File(cacheDir, "shared_images")
            if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {
                val directoryCreated = imagesFolder.mkdir()
                if (!directoryCreated) {
                    // Handle the case where directory creation failed
                    Log.d("directoryTrueCreated", "no")
                } else {
                    Log.d("directoryTrueCreated", "yes")
                }
            }

            val imageFile = File(imagesFolder, "screenshot.png")
            try {
                val fos = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos)
                fos.flush()
                fos.close()
                Log.d("Compression", "Image compressed successfully")
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                e.message?.let { Log.e("Compression", it) }
            }
            imageFile
        }
    }
   private fun shareImage(imageFile: File) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this@Bmi_result,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider",
            imageFile
        )
        val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            type = "image/png"
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        }
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"))


    }
```

the path file i.e. path.xml is as follows

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

I intend to get the image in the form of JPEG/PNG for sharing and not in the .bin format. don't know what to do. everything seems to be correct. i have tried it on the different devices and also using different apps for sharing, but still getting the same result.

Comment: You should compress the bitmap to fos. Dont use an intermediate byte array output stream.

Comment: What is bin format? It is pretty unckear where you get 'the same result'. Where is the share received?

Comment: .bin format here refers to the Binary format , in the form of 0 and 1 , and in almost all  of the devices there is no built-in provision to open the .bin format file . I am receiving the .bin format file in the phone i am sending the image ( which i intend to send in the format of jpeg or png) . my app is simple i had provided the sharing option to the user , through which user can share the BMI result to family or friends . i am using my brothers phone to for receiving the image , which i am sending from my phone where my app is installed. I am receiving .bin format in my brothers phone...

Comment: I do not understand your bin format. A jpg or png file also exists of 0 and 1. How about the file name? Is it the same as sent? How many bytes in resulting file and original file? Is it just a name? Which email app used on receiving side,? Rename the extension to jpg or png.

Comment: thank you brother ... i compress the file to FOS and didn't used the  byte array output stream and now i am not getting the .bin format , finally :) , but now i am not getting any image with any format ,  in the receiving end  . Suppose for whatsapp, as soon as i chose the recipient and click on send button , the whatsapp is giving me the toast as "the file format is not supported" and even in Gmail, it is saying " couldn't attach the file"... Now what to do ..??

Comment: my modified code in the CompressBitmapAsync() function is    val imagesFolder = File(cacheDir, "shared_images")
            imagesFolder.mkdirs()

            val imageFile = File(imagesFolder, "screenshot.png")
            try {
                val fos = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
                fos.flush()
                fos.close()
            }..... after your pointing  out of the file name...your help is really appreciated ....

Comment: Have you checked if the file you compressed to fos is a valid image file?

Comment: actually i don't have any guidance on how to check for it .... can you give directions for it...

Comment: If compressBitmapAsync() is really async then you cannot call shareImage() right after it. Do it later.

Comment: You can display that file in an imageview.

Comment: You could better forget about a screendump first if you dont know if the file is ok. Just select an image file and share it.

Comment: Edit your post with new code. Dont post code in a comment. Unreadable.

Comment: Sir, i have edited the compressBitmapAsync() function only and by applying various logs i had figured out that the imagesFolder exists fine , because the imagesFolder.exists() statement is true and hence the corressponding block is not executed . but i am getting the error /data/user/0/com.example.agepublish/cache/shared_images/screenshot.png: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)                                                                                            for the statement of log inside the catch block . that means try block is throwing some error.kindly help please...

Comment: Sir i am also getting the warning "Inappropriate blocking method call " for the functions FileOutputStream , flush and close function in the compressBitmapAsync function....can it be the possible reason for the error...? please guide sir...

Comment: Remove those statements as at end of compress() the steam got closed already.

Comment: Sir what about the error data/user/0/com.example.agepublish/cache/shared_images/screenshot.png: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)....i am  getting this for the inside the catch block ..that means the try block is throwing the error ...also i had verify for the path of the screenshot.png file and it is created succussfully after the statement                                        val imageFile = File(imagesFolder, "screenshot.png")                                                            the imagesFolder is also getting formed properly (i had verify for that also)...

Comment: `it is created succussfully after the statement val imageFile = File(imagesFolder, "screenshot.png") ` What do you mean with 'after'? If after then tell who created that file. As this statement does not create a file.